# Executing a macro over another excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro
(Macro than rename the sheet with the value of cell B4 and then create one workbook for each sheet.)

```
Sub RenameTabs()
'UpdatebyTony
For x = 1 To Sheets.Count
If Worksheets(x).Range("B4").Value <> "" Then
Sheets(x).Name = Worksheets(x).Range("B4").Value
End If
Next
Dim xPath As String
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xls"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But this means I have to go and copy the macro in each excel file and run it.

I would like to be able to run de macro and it open a dialog where it ask me to choose the excel file that I want to rename the sheets and separate? Is that possible?

I know very little about VBA

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the path of the workbook you like to perform the macro from FileDialog. You can use

> `Application.FileDialog`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx

2. Open the workbook and set a reference for it.

> set wb  =Application.Workbooks.Open(filepath)

3. On your current sub **RenameTabs**, replace **Application.ActiveWorkbook**, **ThisWorkBook** with wb. Also, you need to properly reference the Sheets, Worksheets, ... to wb. Alternatively, you should make it sure that wb is the ActiveWorkbook `(wb.Activate)` (you can break the code if you switch to another excel file when it is still processing)